# Load a Bitmap with Fresco into DraweeView

Tags: android, bitmap, fresco

Is there any way to load a `Bitmap` with `Fresco` into a `DraweeView`?
Somewhat like you can do with `Glide`:

```
Glide.with(context)
    .load(bitmap)
    .into(imageView);
```

Comment: Where is this bitmap from? The devices storage? Your assets folder? Because if the case is that it's from device storage you can simply use `ImageView` as `DraweeView` is not suited for that. What is your reason for using `DraweeView` then?

Comment: The `Bitmap` is created from a cropped image taken from the camera. `ImageView` method is not enough to load big images in [an efficient way](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap).

Comment: Agreed I guess my point is why choose Fresco like the only library to not handle bitmaps as easily, it can if you use `ImageRequest` and a `DrawController` etc, but libs like Picasso and Glide do this much more easily. So why use a library that's not for for purpose? Or easily fit for purpose. Id suggest Picasso I've used it plenty, Glide is just as good

Comment: Project requirements... I completely agree. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Fresco can do these operations for you. From the comments, I see that you want to handle the Bitmap in an efficient way, so you can let Fresco do that.
As to the cropping that you are doing, there are multiple ways to do that with Fresco:

- Use a SCALE_TYPE if you don't need the bitmap: Fresco has more than ImageView, including focus cropping to a given point within the image and you can also implement your own scaling, see https://frescolib.org/docs/scaletypes.html
- If you need the cropped bitmap, you can implement your cropping logic via a Postprocessor (and also cache the bitmap if needed), see https://frescolib.org/docs/modifying-image.html#advanced-changing-the-bitmaps-size

Scale type example:

```
@Override
public void getTransformImpl(
    Matrix outTransform,
    Rect parentRect,
    int childWidth,
    int childHeight,
    float focusX,
    float focusY,
    float scaleX,
    float scaleY) {
  // Your computations, such as for example a fit bottom implementation:
  float scale = Math.min(scaleX, scaleY);
  float dx = parentRect.left;
  float dy = parentRect.top + (parentRect.height() - childHeight * scale);
  outTransform.setScale(scale, scale);
  outTransform.postTranslate((int) (dx + 0.5f), (int) (dy + 0.5f));
}
```

Postprocessor example that can do scaling and blurring from https://github.com/facebook/fresco/blob/master/samples/showcase/src/main/java/com/facebook/fresco/samples/showcase/postprocessor/ScalingBlurPostprocessor.java:

```
public class ScalingBlurPostprocessor extends BasePostprocessor {

  private final Paint mPaint = new Paint();
  private final int mIterations;
  private final int mBlurRadius;
  /**
   * A scale ration of 4 means that we reduce the total number of pixels to process by factor 16.
   */
  private final int mScaleRatio;

  public ScalingBlurPostprocessor(int iterations, int blurRadius, int scaleRatio) {
    Preconditions.checkArgument(scaleRatio > 0);

    mIterations = iterations;
    mBlurRadius = blurRadius;
    mScaleRatio = scaleRatio;
  }

  @Override
  public CloseableReference<Bitmap> process(
      Bitmap sourceBitmap, PlatformBitmapFactory bitmapFactory) {
    final CloseableReference<Bitmap> bitmapRef =
        bitmapFactory.createBitmap(
            sourceBitmap.getWidth() / mScaleRatio, sourceBitmap.getHeight() / mScaleRatio);

    try {
      final Bitmap destBitmap = bitmapRef.get();
      final Canvas canvas = new Canvas(destBitmap);

      canvas.drawBitmap(
          sourceBitmap,
          null,
          new Rect(0, 0, destBitmap.getWidth(), destBitmap.getHeight()),
          mPaint);

      NativeBlurFilter.iterativeBoxBlur(
          destBitmap, mIterations, Math.max(1, mBlurRadius / mScaleRatio));
      return CloseableReference.cloneOrNull(bitmapRef);
    } finally {
      CloseableReference.closeSafely(bitmapRef);
    }
  }
}
```